# How to create textfield with pre text that continue appear after user input

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to create textfield with pre text that continue appear after user input

I trying to create a textfield like e.g

```
[                      yourdomain.com]
```

Then when user type yourdomain.com doesn't disappear, it appear there which can't be remove also. means can't be delete. stay there in the background

```
[            myaccount.yourdomain.com]
```

Comment: Don't do it. It makes the user interface confusing. Place `yourdomain.com` _after_ the text field.

Comment: I suggest `placeholder` html attribute rather than text that stick forever.

Comment: Use the placeholder attribute: `<input type="text" placeholder="yourdomain.com">`. This relies on html5 though so you'll have to polyfill it if you need to support legacy browsers.

Comment: @Colandus looks like we typed those at just about the same time. Upvoted :)

Comment: For this purpose, "placeholder" is not really relevant; it won't help the OP achieve anything like what's desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<input class=actual><input class=show value='.yourdomain.com' readonly>
```

CSS:

```
input.actual {
  text-align: right;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

input.show {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

The "actual" one is the real input field, so you'd also give it a name etc.

[Here is a demo.](http://jsbin.com/OqEPUKo/1)

Answer (score 0):

For HTML input field there are only two types of values. The first one is the „value“ parameter which puts (editable) content in the field. The second parameter is "placeholder" it puts some „description“ in the input field that disappears when the user start typing.

```
<input type="text" value="@yourdomain.com" name="email">
```

or

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your email address: such as me@yourdomain.com">
```

If you want the „suffix“ to appear and disappear you need to use JavaScript. You can access the content of the first input example like this:

```
document.getElementByName("email").value
```

For checking if the user starts or stops typing I would use the focus events (OnFocus) and (OnBlur). So for example you can try to do the following:

```
<input type="text" value="@yourdomain.com" onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="this.value+='@yourdomain.com'">
```

I have not testet that but I guess this should be the right way to solve this problem.

But please think about using one of the first two examples. If the user clicks on a field and the content disappears he might type the „@domain.com“ part him self and then the value of the field will be some sort of this: „me@domain.com@yourdomain.com“. That might confuses the user.